# Is it possible to create a session from a totally different server and carry it over to another server during a POST

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

Can my created session in example.com e.g

```
$_SESSION['unique_id'] = '123423141234';
```

be recognized by another website(on different server)

test.com

```
if(isset($_SESSION['unique_id']))
{
      // if detected.... 
}
```

Where can I learn more about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it's a bad practice even if it's possible. It may expose many security vulnerabilities IMO.

Comment: This is essentially single sign on. These questions may help: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+single+sign+on

Comment: Do you need it for login purpose ?

Comment: No, for captcha matching... third party :) I'm thinking of putting the captcha in one server in a session, then match it in another server via session...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a PHP specific answer but the generic answer is YES. The usual technique is to implement session persistence on the servers, with the store holding the sessions being shared by the various servers. This is one of the techniques used to do clustering or more generally SSO.

How you implement session persistence is very dependent on the container. In my Java world, using Jetty 8 we had to provide our own implementation to suit our needs.

The (shared) persisted sessions are usually stored on a DB but the store can also be a shared FileSystem or even a Distributed Hashmap (check hazelcast for instance)